# Telethon TypeError proxy

Tags: python, proxy, typeerror, telegram, telethon

I'd like to hide my proxy from python code. So I tried to use configparser to do this, but I have problem

```
cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()
cpass.read('config.data')
try:
    api_id = cpass['cred']['id']
    api_hash = cpass['cred']['hash']
    phone = cpass['cred']['phone']
    proxy = cpass['cred']['proxy']
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy)
```

So when I try to start my session I have wrong: **TypeError: Proxy of unknown format: <class 'str'>**
My proxy seted in file config.data like: *proxy = 'socks5', '185.183.162.152', 8030, True, '82DOLD', 'DTANSF'* (thats fake proxy. dont try use)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a proxy to access Telegram, you will need to either:

- For Python **>= 3.6** : install `python-socks[asyncio]`
- For Python **<= 3.5** : install `PySocks`

The allowed values for the argument `proxy_type` are:

**For Python <= 3.5:**

- `socks.SOCKS5` or `'socks5'`
- `socks.SOCKS4` or `'socks4'`
- `socks.HTTP` or `'http'`

**For Python >= 3.6:**

- All of the above
- `python_socks.ProxyType.SOCKS5`
- `python_socks.ProxyType.SOCKS4`
- `python_socks.ProxyType.HTTP`

### Example >= 3.6

```bash
pip3 install "python-socks[asyncio]"
```

```py
from python_socks import ProxyType

my_proxy = {
    'proxy_type': ProxyType.SOCKS5,  # (mandatory) protocol to use (see above)
    'addr': '1.1.1.1',               # (mandatory) proxy IP address
    'port': 5555,                    # (mandatory) proxy port number
    'username': 'foo',               # (optional) username if the proxy requires auth
    'password': 'bar',               # (optional) password if the proxy requires auth
    'rdns': True                     # (optional) whether to use remote or local resolve, default remote
}

TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash, proxy=my_proxy)
```

### Example <= 3.5

```bash
pip3 install PySocks
```

```py
import socks

my_proxy = (socks.SOCKS5, '1.1.1.1', 5555, True, 'foo', 'bar')

TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash, proxy=my_proxy)
```

Comment: I wanted to hide my proxy from python code. For that I create file config.data. All data from config.data is taken, but for some reason there is no proxy